# The most efficient way to implementing similar scenes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

So I'm creating a game with cocos2d, and alot of my scenes (not all, but alot), will have sort of a "scoreboard" you could call it, and they will have the basic principals. I was wondering, how could I make it so the "game scenes" could all implement the scoreboard?

I was thinking this could use something like Categories, but I'm fairly new to iOS/obj-c so I don't know if that's the right approach.

In Java, I could probably just make all the scenes subclasses and have the superclass do all of the scoreboard handling, but I have no idea how to do that in iOS/obj-c.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same solution here. Create subclass of CCScene. Then implement your score logic there. All subclasses of your scene will be able to call these methods. For example, you can create methods showScore/hideScore or smth else. There you can construct and add/remove imstance of your scores to the current scene.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass CCNode or any other class that's appropriate (CCScene, CCLayer, it doesn't really matter). Name this class MyScoreboard. Design your scoreboard node like any other scene by adding nodes to it and positioning them.

Then, wherever you need the scoreboard just create an instance and add it to the node hierarchy:

```
MyScoreboard* scoreboard = [[MyScoreboard alloc] init];
[self addChild:scoreboard];
```

Amend init with parameters (initWithScore:Player:WhatNot:) as needed.